# automaticly redirect link problem on update

Tags: redirect

i recently updated to WP 4.4 and im having a problem with redirect of some portfolio links:

```
http://www.website.com/ecuador-travel-tours/papallacta/
```

is redirecting to

```
http://www.website.com/ecuador-travel-tours/papallacta-hot-springs/
```

any clues why?

Answer (score 0):

thanks to this link I solve the problem:

[Purge Old Slug Redirects](http://wptheming.com/2015/12/purge-old-slug-redirects/)